# Experience the "1-9" hardware failure with wireless keyboard (looking for the custom passkey option)

Tags: macbook-pro

So I've experienced the failure of the 1-9 keys on my wireless keyboard, and was curious how to find the custom passkey option so I can pair it with my MacBook Pro.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What is this "custom passkey option" you speak of?